# How to set pixelwise ink limit for DEVICE=tiffsep1

Tags: ghostscript

I am using ghostscript's tiffsep1 device as a RIP for an inkjet system and want to limit the amount of ink applied per dot. I got the impression that the inklimits from ICC profiles only work on the coarser DitherPPI resolution but not the the DPI. Is there a way to limit on this resolution as well?

For more clarity, see these two images of a (0.75, 0.5, 0, 0) CMYK colored area:

Cyan: [image]
Magenta: [image]

Clearly the upper left pixel is set in both channels, giving 200% ink. If I wanted to limit it to 100%. Even when I give it a "global" inklimit of 100% by scaling down to (0.6, 0.4, 0, 0) CMYK we get this:

Cyan: [image]
Magenta: [image]

so still enough overlapping area where 200% ink would be reached pixelwise.

Is there some setting in ghostscript to avoid this?

PS: I am aware that the situation is worse here because all channels use the same angle and frequency so the cell centers will aways overlap. However, even with default angles we would eventually get some pixelwise overlap in some places which is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't any way to do what you want. You could produce a contone image and halftone it yourself of course.

Comment: I was afraid that this would be the case. Luckily, for now I only need an inklimit of 200% "per pixel" which can be achieved by replacing all 300% and 400% pixels by black, e.g. via ImageMagick postprocessing on the tiffs. This will probably result in some color shifting but for my applicatio this is not as important.